# Perspective of a Point Light

Tags: 3d, lighting, shadows, projection, perspective

I'm trying to calculate shadows by projecting the silhouette of each object seen by the light source.
(The shadows are just going to go on planes.)
To get each silhouette I take a snapshot from the point of view of the light source looking at the object.

But I'm confused what the field of view of the snapshots is analogous to in the real world.
I was thinking perhaps the size of the light source?
But there's both horizontal and vertical field of view, snapshots in all directions, and I'm lost.
So I'm asking what dictates the perspective of these snapshots.

Comment: Field of view does not really apply to a light that shines in all directions. Can you show us how you're trying to use a field of view value in your code? This can help us find the right alternative to work with the approach you're using.